# POSTing to a URL in a controller does not trigger render_template in Flask

Tags: python, angularjs, flask

I suppose this should be very simple but I think I'm missing something.

Simple description: I have a page that lists specific words. Each word has an ID. I'm passing this ID to a function, which then posts it to a URL. What I'm attempting to do is to pass the ID, query it in the backend, and get transferred to the edit page with the query result.

Here's my code:

**AngularJS function**

```
$scope.editDefinition = function (searchItem) {
    var param = { id: searchItem.id };
    var url = "/table-based";
    $http.post(url, param).success(function (data) {
      console.log(data);
    });
  };
```

**Flask/Python route function**

```
@app.route("/table-based", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def edit_definition():
    if request.method == "POST":
        j = json.loads(request.data)
        uid = j["id"]
        cdef = db.getDefinitionById(uid)
        return render_template("edit.html", definition=cdef)
    return render_template("edit.html")
```

**HTML**

```
<div ng-init="init('{{ definition |tojson|safe }}')" ng-controller="editCtrl">
    <ng-include src="'/_partial_edit_form'"></ng-include>
</div>
```

`EditCtrl` has the relevant `$scope.init` function to receive `definition`. Basically, it returns a response that contains the HTML of the `edit.html` template, but it does not redirect to the URL.

What gives?

Comment: Why should it redirect to the URL? All you do is log the response to the console.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't implemented anything that will cause the browser to redirect to your new template page. In the data returned you should just see the html generated by render_template.

You have two options that I can see. The first would be to store the cdef in flask's g or session object and then reload the page with angular $route.reload() or $window.location.reload() and have flask pick up the cdef from g or session on GET.

The second option would be to refactor your code so that you have angular doing the page rendering, then you just update your definition object on POST. In this case, flask would return json.dumps(cdef) instead of the render template and you would use the angular templating to render it.

The second option is much better, and is pretty much exactly what Angular is designed to do. When I create Angular-Flask apps, I very rarely use render_template, instead I have Angular doing all the rendering after retrieving the data as JSON from a flask-based API.

Comment: I think I understand the second option a bit, but can you provide an example snippet of this can be approach based on my above code? I believe this should use `ngRoute`, yes?

Comment: I agree, generally it would be better to have angular do all the routing/location changes. You could do a `return redirect('some_other_view')` if you want to embed an angular app in a traditional flask app where the html is rendered by flask.

Comment: +1 and accept. I've changed my Flask to become a somewhat RESTful API instead and left all routing to AngularJS EXCEPT two instances: login and logout, which I still handle via Flask/Jinja. If you can, kindly see my other question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34854696/). Thank you.