# Link in AngularJS not calling Flask endpoint

Tags: python, angularjs, flask

Code snippets:

**`app.config`**

```
  $locationProvider.html5Mode({
    enabled: true,
    requireBase: false
  });

  $urlRouterProvider
    .when('logout', '/logout')
    .otherwise('/');
```

**`Relevant HTML`**

```
<li><a href="/logout">Logout</a></li>
```

**`Flask endpoint`**

```
@app.route("/logout")
@login_required
def logout():
    logout_user()
    return redirect(url_for("login"))
```

I have also set `<base href="/"></base>` in my HTML's header. Clicking on the link, however, does not result into anything happening (literally nothing happens).

What gives?

Comment: If you have simple one page app, you do not need any redirects on server side. make endpoint with diff url, like /api/logout. When user clicks logout - make http call to /api/logout, on success redirect to proper state.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved this by virtue of reading the AngularJS documentation twice and found [this little gem](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/$location) there. Providing the answer here so that it helps others who are beginning developing in Flask-Angular.

To quote:

> ### Html link rewriting
>
> When you use HTML5 history API mode, you will not need special
>   hashbang links. All you have to do is specify regular URL links, such
>   as: `<a href="/some?foo=bar">link</a>`
>
> When a user clicks on this link,
>
> - In a legacy browser, the URL changes to `/index.html#!/some?foo=bar`
> - In a modern browser, the URL changes to `/some?foo=bar`
>
> In cases like the following, links are not rewritten; instead, the
>   browser will perform a full page reload to the original link.
>
> - Links that contain `target` element
>     Example: `<a href="/ext/link?a=b" target="_self">link</a>`
> - Absolute links that go to a different domain 
>     Example: `<a href="http://angularjs.org/">link</a>`
> - Links starting with '/' that lead to a different base path 
>     Example: `<a href="/not-my-base/link">link</a>`

Basically, changing this:

```
<li><a href="/logout">Logout</a></li>
```

to this:

```
<li><a href="/logout" target="_self">Logout</a></li>
```

solved the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Because the request to logout never reaches your server. You need to create a LogoutController associated with the logout route that actually makes a request to your flask endpoint.

Comment: So what I'm basically missing is a simple `http.get` request?

Comment: Sadly, even adding an `$http.get` function does not trigger the logout.